# Angular Card navigation issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

[image]

**When I click the whole card it should navigate to the project  detail component and then when I click the BID RECEIVED button it should navigate to the bids component but it navigates to project detail page**

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let data of projectdata">
   <div class="card-body" routerLink="/projectdetail/{{data._id}}">
      <div class="bids" routerLink='/bids/5edbd6eb3290c300179cc2f9'>{{data.totalBids}} BIDS RECEIVED</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add the relevant code as it's impossible to tell the issue without you html/ts files

Comment: `<div class="card" *ngFor="let data of projectdata">
     <div class="card-body" routerLink="/projectdetail/{{data._id}}">
         <div class="bids" routerLink='/bids/5edbd6eb3290c300179cc2f9'> 
              {data.totalBids}} BIDS RECEIVED</div>
     </div>
  </div>`

Comment: post your code in the question, not in the comment section